# Using WTL with Codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wtl

I want to try WTL, but problem is i can't use Visual Studio for this. So i've codeblocks on my side. Is there any way i can use WTL with codeblocks ? I mean configuration/settings that i need to  do for this ?

*is it possible to use WTL with codeblocks?*

Just to clear first, i tried google for this. No satisfactory success. So asking this here.

**How can i configure Codeblocks for WTL ?**

Any suggestions, pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible unless you use codeblocks with the MS compiler AND get the version of Windows SDK that contains ATL (new ones don't, AFAIK). WTL is built on top of ATL.

Comment: I do have Windows SDK installed,i'm not sure if it contains ATL. Do you know any specific version of SDK that contains ATL and works with WTL as well ? Do i need to do any settings for it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to [use WTL with the free VC++ 2005 Express](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/WTLExpress.aspx). You may be able to use the same technique with other compilers.